# Display "Name" field instead of "ID" on a "Lookup and Relationship" field that references another "Lookup and Relationship" field that stores ID

Tags: database, ms-access

For some context, imagine I have a basic **Users** table that looks something like the following:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | John Doe |

I have another table called **Reservations** that references the **Users** table in a field called `User ID`. I am able to have MS Access store the ID of the user in the `User ID` field while displaying the user's name in the GUI.

| ID | User ID | Unit ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 (but actually displays the name John Doe) | 5 |

If I have another table called **ReservationComments** that has the lookup and relationship field `ReservationID`. Just like how the `UserID` selector for the **Reservations** shows me the name of the person when I'm selecting a row I'd like for the selector for this to also show me the person's name but it instead shows me the user's ID since that's the actual value that's stored inside of the table.

**Users Table GUI:**

[image]

**Reservations Table User ID selection dropdown:**

You can see that the cell is showing the user's name but the table itself is storing the id of the user

[image]

**ReservationComments Table ReservationID selection dropdown**

I want the part of the dropdown row that the arrow is pointing towards to say the user's name instead of their ID

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the bound column property of the combo/lookup field to bind the correct field, i.e user as against userid.i.e bound to column 1, which is the user name

I have attached some images for clarification.

it seems you are currently binding the user id column/field, column 2.

[image: Bound column property view]

[image: Bound column data sheet view]

[image: bound column query design]

[image: Bound column stored value]